# Car make model dropdown web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I once found a slick looking car make/model dropdown menu web service that advertised form helpers for Ruby on Rails, have subsequently been unable to find this again by Googling for it.... Anybody know the service I am talking about?

Comment: What's "a dropdown menu web service that advertised form helpers"?

Comment: If you go to any automotive website, you’ll see a <select> menu for vehicle make. When you select a make, it will then update the previously blank <select> below it, to show models available for that make of car. I know there is a company that provides a web service for this purpose, and they have pre-made Ruby on Rails form helpers to make life really easy for someone that needs to do this. The problem is, they must have really bad SEO or I am just looking in all the wrong places, because I am totally unable to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Edmunds provides this data for free through an API. You just have to sign-up to get an API key.

See documentation here:
http://developer.edmunds.com/api-documentation/vehicle/

Sign-up to get a key here: http://developer.edmunds.com/index.html

One example of making the call (many more examples given on their site):

```
https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?fmt=json&api_key={your API key}
```

I was looking for exactly this kind of information for motorcycles. From what I can tell the API does not provide motorcycle data, but it seems to have just about everything for cars - Make, Model, Year, Trim, Style, even Maintenance Schedules.

With the json or xml data, you will have to roll your own drop down menus. Edmunds does provide some premade widgets, but they are pretty specific (e.g. return True Market Value), so there is a good chance they won't have exactly what you need.
http://developer.edmunds.com/widgets_and_apps/index.html

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't include form helpers or anything, but here's a Ruby implementation that uses the KBB database to retrieve make/model info:

http://tektastic.com/2008/03/car-or-auto-make-model-year-database.html

I'd probably cron this outside of the app and update the db from time to time, then use collection_select in the app to construct the dropdowns as normal. You could also adapt it to use ActiveResource for live retrieval, but that seems excessive and perhaps bannable by KBB.

Comment: Interesting, since that’s pulling from their database it should stay up to date, too, eh? That might be just what we need. Thanks for the tip, Eric!